# Syntax for a onClick in a Javascript String

Tags: javascript, html

I am having some issues using the proper syntax for an onClick event on a javascript code:

```
out += "<tr><td onclick=pushDetail(" + c + "); >" + // Code keeps going after this line
```

When I click it doesent use do anything of course and this is my output on the site (inspect element):

```
<td onclick="pushDetail(Alfreds" futterkiste);=""> Berlin</td>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you for any help. I could be considered a newbie at HTML and javascript

Comment: Try this `"<tr><td onclick='pushDetail(" + c + ");' >"`. Add the single quotes respectively.

Comment: Don't do that.  Instead, add an event handler.

Comment: @user1852651 and that is wrong

Comment: @epascarello Could you explain?

Comment: This is what I get using user1852651 approach: <td onclick="pushDetail(Alfreds Futterkiste);">Berlin</td>, but the function method is not being called :(

Comment: which is an error since the string is unquoted

Comment: exactly, the string needs to be unquoted correct?

Comment: if you are new at this.... forget that `onclick` even exists and learn how to write unobtrusive event listeners. Add a class to those elements to be able to target them

Comment: Do not build HTML as a string, especially not with embedded event handlers. You will end up pulling your hair out.

Comment: What does the variable `c` hold? A more descriptive variable name would make the code easier to understand.